How to make the outer cog gear go around the smaller cog gear
I have a set of cog gears animating, and I would like the outer rotating cog to go around the smaller cog and then fall back in place. I'm confused how to do this.



I'm confused how the outer cog and the small cog should both be rotating counter-clockwise...

You could make it follow a path and animate its rotation on itself like that:

For the file you share, first thing remove the Generator modifier in the Graph Editor so that you can control the Evaluation Time of your curve:

Then keyframe the Evaluation Time so that at frame 0 it is at the location where it's going to be dragged by the small cog:

At frame 100 make it do a complete turn, keyframe again, also make the interpolation linear with T, and put a keyframe on the gear rotation:

Put keyframe on the gear rotation until the end of its movement around the small gear, again make the interpolation linear:

Put keyframe on the gear rotation until the end of its movement around the big gear:

File: 

Im almost there, but the rotation of the cog isnt spinning correctly, can you please take a look at the file, and let me know what I have dont incorrect.


I've edited my answer, I hope it helps

Thanks for the detailed information, certainly did help.
